# How can I combine (concat) two columns to one in RethinkDB

Tags: json, node.js, database, rethinkdb

i have a table like this:

```
{
"id":  "8ce79ff2-3c33-4a44-87e8-7d4559436ae0" ,
"name":  "Doe" ,
"prename":  "John"
}, {
"id":  "3e611d37-ee45-4af3-96ad-aba09a450d2c" ,
"name":  "Reese" ,
"prename":  "John"
}
```

Now i want to receive the names in one column like this:

```
{"name": "John Reese"},
{"name": "John Doe"}
```

How can i combine these two columns (with a whitespace)?
I've tried something like this but it didn't worked.

```
r.db("bs2").table("customers").map(function(doc){
  return doc("name")+doc("prename");
});
```

I got that result:

```
"var_44("name")var_44("prename")" "var_44("name")var_44("prename")"
```

Also i tried it with .add .map but it didn't worked. When i got a result it returned something with *var_xx("name")* but didn't combined it like strings. Maybe i need a function which returns the string from the object but i didn't found something in the docs.

Greetings,
droidsheep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
r.db("bs2").table("customers").map({
    name: r.row('prename')
      .add(' ')
      .add(r.row('name'))
  })
```